# Haciendo un Módulo Nativo de React Native para usar el Garmin SDK para iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

Estoy intentando implementar el SDK de Garmin para iOS en un módulo nativo para conectar un reloj Garmin a mi aplicación de react-native. He hecho todo lo que dicen los documentos para crear un módulo nativo y puedo inicializar y comenzar a escanear (esto no arroja ningún error y le pide al usuario que habilite el bluetooth, por lo que definitivamente está haciendo algo). Pero el método de la clase que tengo que implementar (didScanDevice) el cuál debería ser llamado cuando encuentra un dispositivo no recibe la llamada. De nuevo, sin arrojar ningún error. Este método si funciona cuando lo levanto en un proyecto native en swift (sin react-native).

Mi pregunta es, ¿podría haber algún problema con los módulos nativos que no permitan que mi clase que implementa el SDK de Garmin se ejecute correctamente?

El módulo nativo se implementa de la siguiente manera:

```
//AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <companion/companion.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"swc"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }
  
  GHInitializer *initializer = [GHInitializer sharedManager];
  [initializer initializeLicense:@"SDK_KEY"];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

```
//RNGarmin.swift
import Foundation
import companion

@objc(RNGarmin)
class RNGarmin: NSObject, GHDeviceConnectionDelegate, GHScanDelegate, GHPairingDelegate {

  public var supportedDevices: [NSNumber] = [NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.venu.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.venu2.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.venu2s.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.venuSq.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivoactive3.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivoactive3m.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivoactive4.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivoactive4Legacy.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivoactive4s.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivoactiveHr.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivosmart3.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivosmart4.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivosmartHr.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivomove3.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivomove3s.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivomoveHr.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivomoveLuxe.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivomoveStyle.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.vivosport.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix5.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix5s.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix5x.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix5Plus.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix5sPlus.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix5xPlus.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix6.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix6Pro.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix6ProSolar.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix6s.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix6sPro.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.fenix6xPro.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.forerunner245.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.forerunner245m.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.forerunner645.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.forerunner645m.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.forerunner945.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.forerunner945lte.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.instinct.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.lily.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.tactixCharlie.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.tactixDelta.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.marqDriver.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.marqAviator.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.marqCaptain.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.marqExpedition.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.marqAthlete.rawValue), NSNumber(value: GHDeviceTypes.marqCommander.rawValue)]

  @objc
  func startScanning() -> Void {
    GHDeviceManager.shared().add(self);
    GHDeviceManager.shared().setScannerDelegate(self);
    GHDeviceManager.shared().scan(forDevices: self.supportedDevices);
    print("Started scanning");
  }

  @objc
  func stopScanning() -> Void {
    GHDeviceManager.shared().stopScan();
    print("Scanning ended");
  }
  
  func didConnect(_ device: GHRealTimeDevice) {
    print("didConnect");
  }
  
  func didDisconnectDevice(_ device: GHRealTimeDevice) {
    print("didConnect");
  }
  
  func didScanDevice(_ device: GHScannedDevice) {
    print("didConnect");
  }
  
  func didPairDevice(_ device: GHRealTimeDevice) {
    print("didConnect");
  }
  
  func didFail(toPairDevice deviceId: UUID, error: Error) {
    print("didConnect");
  }
  
  func didPausePairing(_ completion: GHPairingCompletion) {
    print("didConnect");
  }
  
  func scanDidFailWithError(_ error: Error) {
      print("scanDidFailWithError")
      print(error)
  }
}
```

```
//RNGarmin.m
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RNGarmin, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(startScanning)
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(stopScanning)

@end
```

```
//swc-Bridging-Header.h
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

La salida al correr la aplicación y llamar la siguiente función:

```
useEffect(() => {
    RNGarmin.startScanning();
}, []);
```

es:

```
2021-06-29 09:07:37.366641-0300 swc[2573:736288] Connection 1: received failure notification
2021-06-29 09:07:37.366723-0300 swc[2573:736288] Connection 1: failed to connect 1:50, reason -1
2021-06-29 09:07:37.366757-0300 swc[2573:736288] Connection 1: encountered error(1:50)
2021-06-29 09:07:37.368547-0300 swc[2573:736284] Task <C9118789-39B4-49D1-8BFA-783C2867AAD9>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1009 [1:50])
2021-06-29 09:07:37.373417-0300 swc[2573:736288] Task <C9118789-39B4-49D1-8BFA-783C2867AAD9>.<1> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x280ad0540 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <C9118789-39B4-49D1-8BFA-783C2867AAD9>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <C9118789-39B4-49D1-8BFA-783C2867AAD9>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.2.119:8081/status, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.2.119:8081/status, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2021-06-29 09:07:37.377921-0300 swc[2573:736116] [native] Module RNGarmin requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
2021-06-29 09:07:37.384174-0300 swc[2573:736116] [native] Running application swc ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2021-06-29 09:07:37.412353-0300 swc[2573:736284] Connection 2: received failure notification
2021-06-29 09:07:37.412389-0300 swc[2573:736284] Connection 2: failed to connect 1:50, reason -1
2021-06-29 09:07:37.412410-0300 swc[2573:736284] Connection 2: encountered error(1:50)
2021-06-29 09:07:37.413011-0300 swc[2573:736286] Task <1FC30C05-7B91-4BC1-97DB-348216E88FE8>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1009 [1:50])
2021-06-29 09:07:37.413253-0300 swc[2573:736284] Task <1FC30C05-7B91-4BC1-97DB-348216E88FE8>.<2> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x280ae6220 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1FC30C05-7B91-4BC1-97DB-348216E88FE8>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <1FC30C05-7B91-4BC1-97DB-348216E88FE8>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.2.119:8081/status, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.2.119:8081/status, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2021-06-29 09:07:37.524201-0300 swc[2573:736284] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.524375-0300 swc[2573:736284] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.525439-0300 swc[2573:736284] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.525566-0300 swc[2573:736284] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.525849-0300 swc[2573:736286] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C3] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-06-29 09:07:37.525934-0300 swc[2573:736286] TCP Conn 0x283388580 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.526277-0300 swc[2573:736286] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C4] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-06-29 09:07:37.526464-0300 swc[2573:736286] TCP Conn 0x28338c9a0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.684259-0300 swc[2573:736290] [javascript] Running "swc" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
2021-06-29 09:07:37.687782-0300 swc[2573:736283] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.688130-0300 swc[2573:736283] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.688593-0300 swc[2573:736284] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C5] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2021-06-29 09:07:37.688724-0300 swc[2573:736284] TCP Conn 0x283388580 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2021-06-29 09:07:37.786838-0300 swc[2573:736116] [native] [GESTURE HANDLER] Initialize gesture handler for root view <RCTRootContentView: 0x15de0dba0; reactTag: 1; frame = (0 0; 390 844); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x280adf510>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2804b31c0>>
Started scanning
```

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Perdón! no me di cuenta. Ahora voy levantar la pregunta en el sitio en Ingles. Pero ya dejé la traducción. Gracias por avisar!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved it, at the end I realized the Garmin module had to run on the main thread (not exactly sure why it is that way but since the module is privare and I can only see the interfaces of each module I'am not expecting to get more information).

Once I told react native to run my module on the main thread it started working fine.

Comment: En español por favor pues estás en SO en español